# Powerpoint VBA: Restart each slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint, restart

We are building a kiosk.  Each slide has a video.  Whenever the user navigates or returns to a slide, the video should restart. I have vba code that does this but on 1st run, powerpoint doesn't appear to run the vba.  Is there some sort of intialize module I need to add?

Only code:

```
Public Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)
  ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.ResetSlideTime
End Sub
```

Comment: For some reason, you sometimes need to add an ActiveX control to the slide (or just off the slide) in order to get the page change event to fire.